# Common libraries in many projects

Tags: python, git, oop, virtualenv, pypi

I have few projects and they use some common code. I refactored this code into common library but then a problem arose. How to manage this common code. I've considered some options which are:

1. libraries as soft links in filesystem.
2. libraries as git submodules.
3. dependencies managed with pip/requirements.txt.

What are pros and cons of this solutions? Do you have another proposals? Which one should i choose and why?

I use Git, and python in virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option with virtualenv is really convenient. Just make a requirements file in your project, install the dependencies into your virtualenv, and run the env. Each project can have their own dependencies and virtualenv, and nothing overlaps. You also don't have to worry about installing conflicting modules in your system's Python.

Comment: yes but i don't want to push my library to cheese shop. I think starting own cheese shop just for sake of one tiny library is huge overkill.

Comment: @yakxxx: you don't need the modules to be in pypi to install them in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1, will cause you pain in the long term. Any non trivial library is going to have to break backward compatibility at some stage, and you don't want to have to update apps A,B and C because app D needs some new functionality from the library